# Remote management and allow network account to use screen sharing

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I remote manage some macOS machines, and I have remote management enabled on them.

I also have network accounts able to login into the machine via an OD server that I administer.

What I am unable to do, however, is allow the network connected accounts to use screen sharing to access the machines.

This is possible under the normal screen sharing options, if you select who can access the machine you get the option to allow network accounts, but this option is not there under the remote management settings.

Does anyone know a way to enable this?

Should I look for another VNC/remote connection method.